# Android NDK Installation on ubuntu

Tags: android, android-ndk, ubuntu-12.04, chmod

I downloaded the latest ndk from http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing.
For installing the ndk i used the following command in the terminal.

```
chmod a+x android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin
```

It returned saying chmod: cannot access `android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin': No such file or directory

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `android-ndk-r10d-linux-x86_64.bin`. if you are using ubuntu 64 bit version, you should download `linux-x86_64.bin` one. `darwin` is for Mac OS X, if you have downloaded the right file, use this command

```
chmod a+x android-ndk-r10d-linux-x86_64.bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set Path on Command `android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin` is placed 
and run this line like:

> C:\User\folder Name of android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin placed\
>   chmod a+x android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin